# go routines in ec2 instance

Tags: go, amazon-ec2

Im writing an app in golang, and I'm doing some tests in a [c5.18xlarge ec2](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/c5/) instance from aws, which has 72 vCPUs.

Is it correct to say that the go routines will be distributed among the 72 vCPUs?

Comment: Yes, but can your application scale across 72 vCPUs, with NUMA and a single scheduler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Go 1.5 Release Notes says

> By default, Go programs run with GOMAXPROCS set to the number of cores available; in prior releases it defaulted to 1.

So starting from Go 1.5, the default value should be the number of cores.  Which means that yes, the go routines should be distributed among the 72 CPUs unless you do something like `runtime.GOMAXPROCS(1)`